# Display of dynamically retrieved image using fancybox/ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, fancybox

Having trouble getting fancybox to display my image correctly, I use ASP.NET:

```
<a class="fancybox" rel="group" href="photoreader.aspx?RoomID=7049">
  <img src="photoreader.aspx?RoomID=7049" alt="" />
</a>
```

The IMG displays properly, but the fancybox *navigates* to the "`photoreader.aspx?RoomID=7049`" page?

If I replace "`photoreader.aspx?RoomID=7049`" with "`mytextpic.jpg`" everything works fine.

I'm setting it up using :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".fancybox").fancybox({type: image});
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".fancybox").fancybox({"type": "image"});
});
```

... `image` is a string, not a variable so it needs to be enclosed in quotes.